# How do I eager load multiple foreign keys including an or query from the same table, in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm searching for the captain.entry_date but I'm not able to create the query in a sequelize model.
My problem is that for any ship exists a captain but the ship_captain.captain_id sometimes is null.
For this cases the captain can be found about the route_id.

```
4 Tables : 
    ship, attributes:[id,name], 
    captain, attributes: [id, name, route_id, route_date]
    ship_captain, attributes: [id, ship_id, route_id, captain_id]
    route, attributes: [id, name]
```

```
select ship.name, c.name, c.entry_date 
    from ship left join ship_captain sc on ship.id = sc.ship_id 
            left join captain c on c.id = sc.captain_id or c.route_id = sc.route_id
```

What I've try so far is this but I can't give an OR operator into the last join

```
Ship.hasMany(ShipCaptain, {foreignKey: "ship_id"});
ShipCaptain.belongsTo(Ship, {foreignKey: "ship_id"});
Captain.hasMany(ShipCaptain, {as: "ship_captain_by_id", foreignKey: "captain_id"});
ShipCaptain.belongsTo(Captain, {as: "ship_captain_by_route", foreignKey: "captain_id"});
Captain.hasMany(ShipCaptain, {as: "ship_captain_by_route", foreignKey: "route_id"});
ShipCaptain.belongsTo(Captain, {as: "ship_captain_by_route", foreignKey: "route_id"});

const options = {
    attributes: ["name"],
    include: [
          {
            model: Captain,
            as: 'ship_captain_per_id',
            required: false,
            attributes: ["name","route_date"],
          },
          {
            model: Captain,
            as: 'ship_captain_per_route',
            required: false,
            attributes: ["name","route_date"],
          }
        ],
    }
    
const elements = await Ship.findAll(options);
```

This is only an example code, may be that you want to rearrange the db attributes
but I tried to give my best to clarify the problem. I can't change the customers database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use only one association to get a captain by `captain_id` or `route_id` and not to use two associations and map them yourself then you need to define only one association `hasOne` (instead of `hasMany`) and **always** use the `on` option to join `ShipCaptain` with `Captain` by `OR`:

```js
Ship.hasMany(ShipCaptain, {foreignKey: "ship_id"});
ShipCaptain.belongsTo(Ship, {foreignKey: "ship_id"});
ShipCaptain.belongsTo(Captain, {as: "captain_by_captain", foreignKey: "captain_id"});
...
const options = {
    attributes: ["name"],
    include: [
          {
            model: ShipCaptain,
            required: false,
            include: [{
              model: Captain,
              required: false,
              as: 'captain_by_captain',
              attributes: ["name","route_date"],
              on: {
                [Op.or]: [{
                   id: Sequelize.col('ship_captain.captain_id'
                }, {
                   id: Sequelize.col('ship_captain.route_id'
                }]
              }
            }
            ]
          },
        ],
    }
    
const elements = await Ship.findAll(options);
```

Comment: Hi Anatoly, thanks for your fast answer ! Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. If I try it with ship_captain than sequelize want that I have to extend the name to the sequelize internal alias 'ship.ship_captain'. Also I got: 'missing FROM-clause entry for table "ship_captain' (the same with ShipCaptain). Do you have another proposal ? (you wrote it may be possible to do it with two associations)

Comment: `missing FROM-clause entry for table "ship_captain'  you just need to correct `ship_captain` in Sequelize.col to the actual alias generated by Sequelize

Comment: horido :D your are right - it works. Thx for your help